# Migrating Meteor Project to Other Machine

Tags: node.js, meteor

I tried to migrate my Meteor to other machine, both are Windows 7 but apparently this error popped up when I tried to run the app. What is the cause? I tried registering the package but it said it was already using.

Here is the error:

```
No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: Package not found: standard-app-packages
    at self.api.use (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\tools\bundler.js:132:17)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Program Files (x86)\Meteor\lib\node_modules
    \underscore\underscore.js:78:11)....(truncated)
```

What did I miss out during the transfer? I simply copied the app folder. Did I skip something?

Comment: did you install meteor on the second machine first?

Comment: @ChristianFritz definitely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like the Meteor on your Windows machine is an older version. Some time ago they used the `standard-app-packages` instead of a larger list as a sort of generic shortcut package.

If Meteor can't find this package but Meteor still runs on your machine, its likely that you have an older version of meteor.

Check that the file at `.meteor/release` exists and the version in it matches the version of Meteor on your windows machine.

Comment: I have checked the version. The original PC and the project use 0.8.0 while the newly installed is unreleased version. When I created new app, i checked the version is none. How can I uninstall the unreleased version of meteor?

Comment: To uninstall recent versions of meteor on Windows, just delete everything under %LOCALAPPDATA%\.meteor and then re-install with LaunchMeteor.exe. If it is an old build of meteor you may need to uninstall it via 'add/remove programs'.